# Send Post Data and redirect to another page without AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, redirect

I have a form with action. The main issue to create redirect to another page without AJAX send data for the current page (in action) and redirect to another page. Is it possible or it's PHP?

```js
const formElem = document.getElementById('form');

        formElem.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            //e.preventDefault();

            window.location.replace('https://dhge.org/pay/{{ uuid }}/');
        })
```

```html
    <form method="post" action="https://www.tfaforms.com" class="hintsBelow" id="form" role="form">
      <div class="jForm__row jForm__row-margin" id="tfa_1-D">
      <label id="tfa_1-L" class="jForm__label" for="tfa_1">First Name<span> *</span></label>
      <div class="jForm__field">
      <input type="text" id="tfa_1" name="tfa_1" required value="" title="First Name " data-dataset-allow-free-responses="" class="jForm__input">
      </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. You are wanting to redirect via JS instead of the location in the form action while still processing the form? How will you know the form processed successfully?

Comment: So here's the problem: without AJAX, the only way to get data from the current page to taforms.com is by submitting the form normally, which will load up taforms.com as a result. Once that happens, you're no longer on the current page. It may be possible that the submit handler will fire after the request is sent and redirect to the page you want, but if it's not working the way you have it, then it probably won't as the page gets unloaded by the submission. It there a reason you don't want to use AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.location.href to redirect

```
document.location.href= 'https://dhge.org/pay/{{ uuid }}/'
```

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't work, because I must to prevent the form

Answer (score 0):

Send data as ajax to a php control that returns data in JSON format, then handling that data you redirect to the next page, or redirect via php itself using the header function on the form's target page.